# Why in System.Logger is log(DEBUG, msg) used instead of debug(msg)?

Tags: java, logging, java-9

I am reading System.Logger API that was introduced in Java 9. And I can't understand why they developed so `strange` API:

```
System.Logger {
  public default void log(Level level, String msg){...}
}
```

I call it `strange` because all popular logging frameworks (I know) don't put level as argument, but name the calling method by level name. For example:

```
//Log4j
logger.error("This is error : " + parameter);
//SLF4J
logger.debug("Printing variable value: {}", variable);
//apache.commons.logging
log.debug(Object message);
//and even sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger
logger.warning(String msg)
```

How to explain it?

Comment: Maybe because `#log` method has many overloads (consuming Object, String, String + Objects, String + Throwable, Supplier), so making all combinations would be cumbersome?

Comment: @AlexSalauyou See slf4j logger - https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html. For example debug method is overloaded 10 times.

Comment: Every logging library that I have worked with has this generic `log(level, message)` API. It is not strange, it is useful in some situations. I used it many times, when my application needed to decide, whether to log something with WARN or ERROR level. I extracted the logging to a method a decided between WARN and ERROR, e.g. based on a boolean flag. So the real question is, why did not Java 9 API also include dedicated methods (log.debug, log.info ...) to the API too

Comment: It's hard to answer questions about developers intentions unless you are the developer. Note that this is not intended to be a logging platform that you use, but rather an interface that allows you to connect the system logging to whatever logging platform you use. So ease of implementation is important.

Comment: slf4j is an external library, specially designed, and System.Logger is not a replacement. External ibraries are to be used when a developer needs rich functionality and usability provided by the library, in other cases, he makes do with built-in functionality, maybe paying a little extra code for that.

Comment: As someone who runs Fortify scans on code, my guess would be it's more of a security perspective.  When you add .debug() calls in your code, you are adding debugging logic that goes to production.  While they are intrinsically the same, a parameter value can be changed during run-time, so passing a Level parameter may not be considered or flagged as being debug logic in your code base.

Comment: **Opinion based**: I would second the thought that the current syntax seems more flexible in moving logs from one level to another based on some *configuration* which in current logging frameworks you can only set the Level to be logged and what would be the Level of the code you select. You do not have the flexibility to say `log.debug("This shall be logged as INFO sometime tomorrow");` <~ just for an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions about the intentions of developers are inherently difficult to answer, unless you are the developer.

That being said, we do have access to the original proposal for this feature - [JEP 264](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/264).

The summary:

> Define a minimal logging API which platform classes can use to log messages, together with a service interface for consumers of those messages. A library or application can provide an implementation of this service in order to route platform log messages to the logging framework of its choice. If no implementation is provided then a default implementation based upon the java.util.logging API is used.

From the goals:

> Be easily adoptable by applications which use external logging framework, such as SLF4J or Log4J.

From the non-goals:

> It is not a goal to define a general-purpose interface for logging. The service interface contains only the minimal set of methods that the JDK needs for its own usage.

So what we have here is not "Yet another logging framework" like SLF4J, Log4J, etc. What we have is an interface that allows you to tell the JVM to use the same logging tool that you are using for the classes in your application, for logging its own stuff.

The typical usage scenario would be an application which has a complex setup in, say, SLF4J, logging to console, files, databases, or sending text to phones. You want the JVM classes to use the same system. So you write an adapter - a class that implements the `System.Logger` interface, using your SLF4J setup.

It's not that you can't use the current system logger for logging - you can - but that's not what it was created for. It was created for you to implement and set the system logger so that it calls your logging framework of choice.

In its current form, when you implement, you only need to implement four methods:

- `getName()`
- `isLoggable(System.Logger.Level)`
- `log(System.Logger.Level, ResourceBundle, String, Object...)`
- `log​(System.Logger.Level, ResourceBundle, String, Throwable)`

Now, `System.Logger.Level` has seven levels. Imagine if instead of having to implement two logging methods, you had to implement 14 logging methods? And more often than not, those implementation would look exactly the same, with one little name change. This is not wise.

As it stands, almost every existing logging framework has a `log(level,...)` method, and then the implementation of `System.Logger`'s `log(...)` can usually be done simply by mapping from the `System.Logger.Level` to your framework's definition of Level.

---

And if you want to log a message?

Well, if you are using a complex logging platform, you log your message there directly, you don't need to go through the system logger. If you insist on using it - you'll need to use the levels as arguments or write your own wrappers. This is simply not the use case the developers had in mind.

Comment: You wouldn't need to implement all those methods if `default` methods delegated to the 4 methods you listed above, so it's a poor reason.

Comment: @john16384 That's not the reason. The reason, as I said, is that the System logger is not intended as a general logging framework.